# Creating and updating a new column in hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I am new to SQL and Hive. I have a table in hive where I need to add 2 columns. One is "row_id" and other is "cto_id". I have added the row id using hive function and a new column called "cto_id".

I want to updated the values in "cto_id" column such as it contains values like "CTO1101"+row_id

how can I do it? Below is my code.

```
-- assigning row number to each record in mu_temp_trials table
select *, row_number() over() as row_id from mu_temp_trials;

--adding new column for primary key in mu_temp_trials
alter table mu_temp_trials add columns(cto_id string);
//update mu_temp_trials set cto_id = "CTO_1101"+row_id; - I want to write this code in hive
```

Comment: You could set up a trigger to set the `cto_id`

Comment: @Adam I need to update the column cto_id and would need that for further use. what hive code can be used to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps!

```
#let's say table mu_temp_trials has two columns - col1 & col2    
ALTER TABLE mu_temp_trials ADD COLUMNS(cto_id STRING, row_id STRING);


INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE mu_temp_trials
SELECT  a.col1, a.col2, concat_ws('','CTO1101',cast(a.row_id as string)) AS cto_id, cast(a.row_id as string) AS row_id
FROM (SELECT  col1, col2, row_number() over() AS row_id FROM mu_temp_trials) a;
```

*Don't forget to let us know if it solved your problem :)*

Comment: @Vaibhav if you liked the solution then you should accept it as the right answer. It'll surely help others in case they encounter similar problem in future. Thanks!