# Adding new column with values concatenating from existing columns in hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, datatables

I have a table with multiple columns. Now I want to add another column which should have values like "CTO1101"+row_id
row_id is the existing column in table.

using below 2 commands is giving error.

```
alter table d_study add columns(cto_id string);

update d_study
    set cto_id = "CTO1101" + row_id;
```

Comment: Not going to happen. Hive UPDATE currently supports only hard-coded values. You can generate a view over your table,create a new table or overwrite your current table after you have added the additional column.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz hey, your approach worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: @vaibhav It's a duplicate question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45438453/creating-and-updating-a-new-column-in-hive

Comment: @Prem yeah, but was just trying to found the answer. got better suggestion here. could you pls help answer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45491829/updating-unique-id-column-for-newly-added-records-in-table-in-hive

Answer (score -1):

`alter table d_study add column cto_id string;` 
`update d_study set cto_id="CTO1101"||row_id;`

The syntax depends on the DB system as well as the data types so for Hive just search for the concatenation opperator("||" or a predefined function )

Comment: getting following error while updating : ParseException line 1:38 missing EOF at '|' near '"CTO1101"'

Comment: update d_study set cto_id=concat('CTO1101',row_id); Try the concatenation function then.

Comment: yes tried that also. got this error - Attempt to do update or delete using transaction manager that does not support these operations. 

I tried for both concat("CTO1101"+row_id) and concat("CTO1101"+str(row_id))

Comment: Then it seems that the problem is now not a syntax problem :). Please see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34198339/attempt-to-do-update-or-delete-using-transaction-manager-that-does-not-support-t) -

Comment: thanks, can you pls help answer this as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45491829/updating-unique-id-column-for-newly-added-records-in-table-in-hive