# Updating unique id column for newly added records in table in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, bigdata

I have a table in which I want unique identifier to be added automatically as a new record is inserted into it. Considering I have column for unique identifier already created.

Answer (score 0):

hive   can't update the table but you can create a temporary table or overwrite  your first table.
you can also use `concat` function  to join the two diferent column or string.
here is the examples

```
function :concat(string A, string B…)  
return: string  

hive> select concat(‘abc’,'def’,'gh’) from dual;  
abcdefgh
```

HQL &result

```
insert overwrite table stock select tradedate,concat('aa',tradetime),stockid ,buyprice,buysize ,sellprice,sellsize from stock;
20130726    aa094251    204001  6.6 152000  6.605   100
20130726    aa094106    204001  6.45    13400   6.46    100
```